# Configuring unity for individual workspaces

Tags: unity, compiz, configuration, workspaces

Is there a way to make visible only the launchers on the current workspace in unity?

Truthfully, would just like to keep separate programs on separate workspaces, I'm making "panic button"

Answer (score 1):

If you have compizconfig settings manager (ccsm) there is a plugin called 'scale' it will show you all windows open on current workspace.[image]